# android 4.0.3 emulator orientation. Bug? or it's my system fault?

Tags: android, emulation

Just today I have downloaded "adt-bundle-windows-x86" with eclipse and sdk inside.
It's really great. But when I've created emulator of android :GOOGLE_API 4.0.3; I've got this one:

[image: Thats how emulator looks like on Windows 32]

after pressing CNTRL + F11 
I got:
[image: orientation changed]

What can be wrong?Is it problem in my OS ? How can I repair it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the reason. I adopted to choose "HVGA". 
But now there is no just "HVGA" but "HVGA slider".
That's why orientation is like this. 
Now we just should use "QVGA"
Sorry it's my mistake. 
Thanks for all answers

Comment: @Bigflow,Yeah its good but it's strange. I had created emulator with the same options as this one on screenshots but for API 2.3.3. And everything is great. It should be a bug on one side or another.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code at the start of your program:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Also add this in your manifest file (under activity):

```
 android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

Comment: I can start my programm, but its wide!I have all this stuff in my code :(

Comment: @BAZTED Already tried to make a new emulator? (like MoshErsan suggested).

Comment: Ok. I've created a new project with RequestedOrintation and it changes to verical and work well. But it should be a bug. When I close my Activity. Orientation changes to the previous.

Comment: @BAZTED Then I don't know, I always test on the device. This was the only thing I could think of.

Comment: I've found a solution. and posted it as answer. It's my mistake of choosing the device.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing CTRL + F11 to rotate back.

Comment: it will be ok but still wide)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in most times I have to restart the emulator.

Comment: restarting emulator even recreating it doesn't solve this bug(

Comment: ops, seems different from my problem, btw try to create new emulator.